# excel last date before

Tags: excel, date, formula

I need help in this situation (Excel 2016):

First column is filled with random valid dates, repeated occurrences are allowed. In second column I need a formula (not macro) yielding the last date *before* that date in first column.

For example (format: year.month.day.)

```
2006.03.07. 2005.06.25.
2015.03.04. 2012.10.27.
2007.07.02. 2006.03.07.
2006.03.07. 2005.06.25.
2005.06.25. ?
2012.10.27. 2007.07.02.
2015.03.04. 2012.10.27.
```

Thank you

Comment: If you try to reference the same column that the formula is in, you get a circular reference.

Comment: First column contains no formulas. Second column contains references only to first column. To be clear: all the cells of second column contains the same formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14, 7, (A$1:A$7)/(A$1:A$7<A1), 1), "?")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, say E2:E8, place a list of your left-hand column (assumed to be `A` starting Row1) dates in ascending sort order and label the list `?`. Then in the right hand column, Row1:

```
 =INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A1,E:E,0)-1)
```

copied down to suit.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but it is not what I need. I need one formula that works without any helping list, any sorting or whatsoever.